# How to upload video from iPhone to iis media services

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

Has anyone idea about IIS Media services. I want to stream video recorded from iPhone. Has anyone know how to upload video to IIS Media services? I found this url but in this they are using expression encoder 4

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/854/apple-http-live-streaming-with-iis-media-services

Please help me i am working on Video streaming application in which i have to upload continuous video to server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understand the linked article, it solves the problem pretty much opposite to the one you are facing: they are configuring IIS to stream content in a way understandable by iPhone.

Comment: @Olaf in the article they configured the IIS Media services and uploaded the video using Expression Encoder 4. By this i able to setup IIS Media Services in my IIS but i want to upload video using iPhone not anyother program or tool. I want iPhone video streaming.